# Python generators to generate iterators

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am following up online course for Python basic, and got stuck with a quiz about generator:
I have access to the solution, but I don't want to directly see it.
I want to make output as below, without using enumerate but by using generator.
I have below pre-written piece of code to start, but I cannot understand why they put start=0.
Could someone help me out to have some leads ? I still want to make output myself, but dont know how should I start.

Expected output:

```
Lesson 1: Why Python Programming
Lesson 2: Data Types and Operators
Lesson 3: Control Flow
Lesson 4: Functions
Lesson 5: Scripting
```

Code:

```
lessons = ["Why Python Programming", "Data Types and Operators", "Control Flow", "Functions", "Scripting"]

def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    # Implement your generator function here


for i, lesson in my_enumerate(lessons, 1):
    print("Lesson {}: {}".format(i, lesson))
```

Thank you!

Comment: `start=0` represent a parameter with a default value. It is only for you to specify the index from which you want to start your iteration (I guess). It has nothing to do with the actual generator to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You have given everything, you just have to return from that function my_enumerate()

**start=0** is for default value. In case if there is no value provided in this parameter when this function will be called from somewhere else. So it will assign it 0, but here when you are calling this function, you are passing 1 as a parameter, so the start variable becomes 1 now.

Your print line in for loop shows the way what you have to print and your given output makes it more clear.

You have given lessons array, on which you have to just iterate and return the result from function, but here you have to return again and again from function as it is calling in for loop, so for this purpose, we will use **yield** keyword.

Your function will be like this:

```
def my_enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    for a in iterable:
      yield (start, a)
      start += 1
```

What this code is doing?

It is just iterate on providing list and return from the function that start variable and list element, and then increment the start, so next time it has the next element of that list

To understand yield concept in detail: Click [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/python-generators-and-yield-keyword/)